# Define a matrix of int with array, list or map in OCaml?

Tags: types, ocaml

I need to define a matrix of int as a type. A column or a row of a matrix represent a `city`, an element in a matrix represent the `distance` between the city of row and the city of the column. The dimension of the matrix may change (we may add or remove cities), but it is always quite small.

I hesitate among `int array array`, `int list list` and a type with `map` which is defined as follows:

```
module MatOrd = struct 
  type t = string * string
  let compare ((a, b): string * string) ((c, d) : string * string) = 
    if Pervasives.compare a  c <> 0
    then Pervasives.compare a c 
    else Pervasives.compare b d
end

module MatMap = Map.Make(MatOrd)
```

Then `int MatMap.t` could represent a matrix of int. An advantage of this definition is I can directly write the name of a city as a coordinate of the matrix. Wherease for `int array array` and `int list list`, it seems that I have to memorize the signification of the coordinates by heart...

Besides, is it true that we can't do pattern-matching with an array? For instance, can't we write:

```
match a_array with
  [| first_element; the_rest_elements |] -> ...
```

With the advantages and disadvantages that I mentioned or not, which type do you suggest?

Comment: You can't write `match a_array with [| first_element; the_rest_elements |] -> ...` because that's not how you access the elements of an array. `the_rest_elements` neither exists in memory and nor has a type in the type system. But you can perfectly well do pattern-matching with arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The applicability of this or that type *really* depends on which operations you mean to implement with it. What will you compute with your type ?

For example, you might want to avail yourself of matrix operations implemented somewhere such as [min-plus multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-plus_matrix_multiplication), which may help you with a shortest path problem. In that case, it makes sense to use matrices, and have a separate function `string -> int` that translates from city name to matrix coordinates. On the other hand, if you just want a datastore on which computation will be scarce, a `Map` type such as the one above might make better sense.

It's hard to give very insightful answers without knowing what you want to compute, but as for your proposals:

- remember lists are immutable, hence `int list list` has a limited utility
- if you make two-dimensional arrays, beware arrays are mutable references and that affectation is treated accordingly, so that after the following:

  ```
  let a = Array.make 3 0;;
  let a = b;;
  b.(0) <- 42;;
  ```

  `a.(0)` equals `42`.

  The language has an eager evaluation strategy so that another caveat is that you shouldn't create an array the following way:

  ```
  let m = Array.make 2 (Array.make 3 0);;
  m : int array array = [|[|0; 0; 0|]; [|0; 0; 0|]|]
  m.(0).(0) <- 1;;
  - : unit = ()
  m;;
  - : int array array = [|[|1; 0; 0|]; [|1; 0; 0|]|]
  ```

  The inner `make` call gets evaluated first, and the same reference is shared by the three 
  lines of your outer array. See [the FAQ](http://caml.inria.fr/resources/doc/faq/core.en.html#matrices) on how to create matrices.

And by the way, you can do pattern-matching on arrays (the [relevant manual section](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/patterns.html#pattern) shows the pattern at the bottom of the page), but you have to respect the dimension of your array when placing pattern variables. Thankfully you can use `_`, and as you said the dimension of your array is quite small.

Comment: Good links and reasonable answer, generally, but I don't think you mean "passed by name" in that second bullet point.  Ocaml doesn't ever use "pass by name" semantics.  Here's a description of what "pass by name" semantics actually are: http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/Teaching/383/PassByName.html  Further, it's because they're <b>not</b> passed by name and instead the argument to the outer constructor is passed by value (and hence only evaluated once) that the näive 2-d array creation fails.

Comment: Of course ! Corrected at length to eliminate any ambiguity/mistake